# if statement being disregarded in a PnPPowerShell loop

Tags: content-type, pnp-powershell, if-statement

I am trying to iterate through a collection of document libraries and run code on the ones that are of a particular Content-Type. The if statement is being disregarded entirely and the `write-host $contentType.Name` is firing for every list in the foreach block.  What is wrong with the if statement?

```
function PopulateData($web, $includeFileSize) {
         Write-Host "Current Site " $web.url -ForegroundColor Cyan 
         #$libs = Get-PnPList -Web $web | Select-Object AllowContentTypes | Where-Object{($_.AllowContentTypes -eq $true)}
         $libs = Get-PnPList -Web $web | Where-Object{($_.BaseType -eq 1)}
         foreach($lib in $libs) {
         write-host "Library Title ############# " $lib.Title
         $ContentTypes = Get-PnPContentType -List $lib

            foreach($contentType in $ContentTypes) {

                if($contentType.Name -eq 'Knowledge Document' -or 'TELL Document') {
                write-host $contentType.Name

            }
         } 
    }
}
```

Comment: needs to be `if(($contentType.Name -eq 'Knowledge Document') -or ($contentType.Name -eq 'TELL Document'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code block:

```
foreach($contentType in $ContentTypes) {
    if($contentType.Name -eq 'Knowledge Document' -Or contentType.Name -eq 'TELL Document') {
        write-host $contentType.Name
    }
}
```

See examples given in below article for more clarification:

[PowerShell Basics: If -And & If -Or Statements](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/if-and/).